# Probability of another distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An oil company conducts a geological study in a particular area of a Middle Eastern country to see whether they can form a new oil company in the area.

Preliminary research indicates that an exploratory oil well in this area should have a 35% chance of striking oil.

How do I calculate the probability that the second strike comes on the fifth wells drilled?

Comment: Do you know the formula $P(n,k)$ for exactly $k$ successes in $n$ binomial trials where each trial has probability $p$ of success? If so, can you see how $P(4,1)$ relates to your question?

Comment: @quasi do you  mean binomial distribution ?  ?

Comment: is this binomial distribution with n = 2, p = 0.35 and k = 5 ?

Comment: You want one success in the first $4$ trials (probability $P(4,1)$), followed by one more success (probability $p$).

Comment: The binomial probability formula is
$$P(n,k)=\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}$$
where$\;k$ is the number of successes in $n$ trials,$\;p$ is the probability of success in any one trial, and$\;q=1-p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second strike comes on the fifth wells drilled means that one strike comes among the first four strikes and the second strike comes in the fifth strike. So we have the following events:

$A=\textrm{One strike comes among the first four strikes}$

$B= \textrm{Second strike comes in the fifth strike}$

And we are looking for $P(A \cap B)$. Since the two events $A,B$ are mutually independent we have $P(A \cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$. For the event A we can write down all ways with $\textrm{s=strike}$ and $\textrm{n= no strike}$.

$$\color{blue}snnn \quad n\color{blue}snn \quad nn\color{blue}sn \quad nnn\color{blue}s$$

Thus there are $4$ ways for event $A$. Every event has the probabilty $0.35\cdot (1-0.35)^4$. Therefore $P(A)=4\cdot 0.35\cdot 0.65^3$. Can you evaluate $P(B)$?